# Multiplayer game with differently screen size

Tags: c++, sdl2

I am making a classic ping pong 2D multiplayer and its run on full screen, but i have a problem that the ball touch the limits of screen to one player and other no. Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use screen pixels as a unit of length for your game.
You could use an abstract scene in arbitrary units, compute the ball position in this scene (independently of the players' screen resolution) and then transform the scene coordinates into screen coordinates depending on the screen resolution.